# .Net Core API same url different tenant payload

Tags: .net, .net-core, architecture, multi-tenant

I am working on a project which is not exactly multi-tenant, but we have multiple customers with on-premise apps and one of the requirement is to have a single codebase for all of them. Currently every customer has either a fork of the original codebase or has a special branch on the common repo.
Over the years custom code was mode for each of them which results in differences in the database, business logic and front-end.

For the REST API that we are building, I am trying to find a clean way to use the same url for every client, but payload can vary as well. I need to be able to call the appropriate controller depending on configuration.
For clientA, POST /api/visitor might have a payload shape of {Name, Age}, clientB it might be {Name, CardNumber, Height}.

I tried to move the controllers to their own projects in the solution and use AddApplicationPart(clientAssembly), but since all the projects are referenced in the api project, endpoints.MapControllers() crashes due to the name conflict. If I make this work, it would require to deploy code for every customer due to the project references and I don't think it's a good idea.

I also looked into using the new .net core 3 dynamic routing feature, but I think its supposed to be used for transforming the request more than adding context to it.

Has anybody run into this? Should I just skip all of that and include the "tenant" in the URL of every route (this solution probably will be refused)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating multiple versions of your API. Below is a non-exhaustive example but something that can map your problem to a solution domain. This will help you make your domain, api and services co-exist with mapping to their own versions. Also at a later point of time, you can migrate your old version API consumers to the latest version and stop maintaining the very older versions (like making obsolete). Most of the public API's that we have today out in the web follow this model.

```
namespace Models.V1.Customer {
    public class Customer {

        public Guid Id;
        public string Name;
        public string Address;
        public int Zip;
    }
}

namespace Models.V2.Customer {
    public class Customer: Models.V1.Customer {
        public Location CustomerLocation;
    }
}


[RoutePrefix("api/customers/")]
public class CustomerAPIController : IHttpController {

    [Route("v1/byId/{Id}")]
    public Models.V1.Customer GetCustomerById(Guid Id) {
        // calls to get the customer data by id
    }

    [Route("v2/byId/{Id}")]
    public Models.V2.Customer GetCustomerById(Guid Id) {
        // calls to get the customer data by id
    }
}
```

You can read more on this topic from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning)

Hope this clarifies your question.